# defined character getting name errors in python

Tags: python, nameerror

i am very new to python and am trying to run some code for class, however I am coming into a weird error note I just put in a random value for n and k to see if the code would work

```
$python main.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "main.py", line 10, in <module>
 while(k):
 NameError: name 'k' is not defined
```

here is my code, I have defined n and n works with no problem, but k seems to be an issue

```
def binary(n,k):
  n = 6 
  k = 1.5
    #'n' is the fractional number 
     #'k' is the number of bits up to the loop ; 
  integral = int(n) 
  fraction = n-integral 

 b = '.'
 while(k):
     fraction = fraction * 2
     fra_num = int(fraction)
     if (frac_num == 1):
         fraction = fraction - frac_num
         b = b + '1'
     else:
         b = b + '0'
         k = k - 1
 print b
```

Comment: Fix you indentation. That's why you are getting this error.

Comment: thank you for commenting! which line exactly has the indentation problem?

Comment: Just a FYI: you are learning to use an obsolete, deprecated, unsupported version of Python. Convince your teacher to switch to a modern version such as 3.8.

Answer (score 1):

As commented, your biggest problem here is your indentation. Your while loop is not inside your function. Try this for indentation:

```
def binary(n,k):
    n = 6 
    k = 1.5
    #'n' is the fractional number 
    #'k' is the number of bits up to the loop ; 
    integral = int(n) 
    fraction = n-integral 

    b = '.'
    while(k):
        fraction = fraction * 2
        fra_num = int(fraction)
        if (frac_num == 1):
            fraction = fraction - frac_num
            b = b + '1'
        else:
            b = b + '0'
            k = k - 1
    print b
```

Comment: The line after ```while(k):``` is not properly indented. Please fix it.